# How can I configure koa-router to run common code before any of a certain group of routes?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

I'd like to add some functionality to `/module` that gets executed for any matching route under that directory.

So for a given set of routes:

```
/module/
/module/page
/module/things
/module/things/:thingid
```

I want code in a router for `/module` to run for all of the above routes. `/module` doesn't render, it just fetches some common data and configures the view context. Then one of the other routes runs and renders the page.

Is this possible with koa-router? Or is there a better package?

Edit:
I think maybe I have to do a nested router and add middleware prior to the nesting like so:

```
var subRouter = new Router();
subRouter.get('/', function *(next){ doSomething(); });
subRouter.get('/page', function *(next){ doSomething(); });
subRouter.get('/things', function *(next){ doSomething(); });
subRouter.get('/things/thingid', function *(next){ doSomething(); });

mainRouter.use('/module',
               function *(next) { doPreRouteSteps(); yield next; },
               subRouter.routes()
);
```

Seems to be working, but I'm not sure if this is an ugly hack or what. If there is a better way, please advise.

Comment: That looks like a sensible approach (i.e. not a hack). If you're interested in alternative routing middleware check out https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki#routing-and-mounting.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [koa-mount](https://github.com/koajs/mount) to create a separate app, and then mount it under `/module`. The sub-app can have any pre- or post- middleware you'd like.

```
var mount = require('koa-mount');
var koa = require('koa');
var koaRouter = require('koa-router');

var subApp = koa();
var router = koaRouter();
router.get('/page', function *(next){ ... });
subApp.use(function*() { ...pre-route stuff... });
subApp.use(router.routes());

var mainApp = koa();
mainApp.use(mount('/module', subApp));
```

I like this approach because the way it encourages modularity.

Answer (score 2):

koa-router can do this, i guess better.

```
router.use('/module/', function *(next) {
  // code here
  next();
});

router.get('/module/page', function *() {
  this.body = 'your view';
});
```

on this sample, everytime the router encounters '/module'. even if there are trailing or additional params on the url. it will run the first function then proceed to any meet condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is Rei Dien's response updated to 2021. Also you can pass an array of routes or `"/"` which will call your `router.use()` before any route. Example with array of routes:

```js
    router.use(["/user", "/posts"], async (ctx, next) => {
        // Your code before routes...
        await next();
    });

    router.get("/user/likes", async ctx => {
        ctx.body = "Your rute code...";
    });
```